# Polarion SDK: Set document name in workflow context

Tags: javascript, java, function, polarion

I am trying to set the document ID from ScriptFunction. I tried:

`workflowContext.getTarget().setId("Demo");`

But it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set an Id of a IWorkflowObject. you may want use the `IModule.move(java.lang.String newModuleFolder, java.lang.String newModuleName)` function.

see sdk doc here:
https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/alm/tracker/model/IModule.html#move(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Due to the nature of the SVN storage it may not work but breaks with a broken transaction.

I cannot test it at the moment.

Comment: Thank you @peter. I think this is so beneficial.
However, I tried: \n

`var workitem = workflowContext.getTarget();
var moduleFolder = workitem.getModuleFolder();
workitem.move​(moduleFolder, "newName");`

And it is returning : _workitem.move​ is not a function in_ 


Do you have any idea why. In all cases thank you for your help

Comment: It seems you are operating on an IWorkItem object. My comment related to the Workflow of a Document. Did you configure the workflow function for the Document or the Workitem workflow? AFAIK it is not possible to change the Id of a WorkItem.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I tried it for document in workflow context.
And it was giving the error workflow.move is not a function.
Sorry for this.

Comment: you are right. you get an IWorkflowObject back which does not have the appropriate object methods. So you need to retrieve the instance of the IModule and apply the move there. You can use the 
var mm =workitem.getTrackerService().getModuleManager() 
to get the modulemanager instance  but you need a ILocation object to get the IModule you need .. this is a pretty f***ed up API at this place..